# npm err! registry error parsing JSON tried many solution but still getting issue

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I'm following [This blog](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/) and trying to install yeoman using:

**npm install -g yo**

*but getting following error:*
**npm ERR! registry error parsing json**

I have tried every solution that I found on internet but nothing worked for me.

**My system configuration is:**

**OS** : Windows-7 64 bit

**Node version** : 0.11.16

**npm version** : 2.3.0

I tried npm cache clean, uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs and tried with diff version of nodejs, cleaned temp folder and even restarted my system.

Please provide some feasible solution for this

What could be the reason behind it?
Is it related to some unstable node and npm version? If yes then which version is the most stable so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution:**

Installed node version 0.10.36  and it solved my purpose